# How to apply regression to a zoo data frame in R?

Tags: r, curve-fitting, zoo

I have a zoo data frame, a piece of which looks like:

```
                TLT      PCY      SHY
2015-04-15 122.1545 28.16594 84.63730
2015-04-16 123.9836 28.11196 84.72825
2015-04-17 124.4341 28.07958 84.70804
2015-04-20 125.2258 28.15514 84.74845
2015-04-21 125.9629 28.18753 84.76866
2015-04-22 126.1267 28.28469 84.79897
2015-04-23 126.4923 28.30628 84.85056
2015-04-24 124.5478 28.34947 84.81010
2015-04-27 123.3290 28.36026 84.63820
2015-04-28 124.3560 28.38185 84.83033
2015-04-29 123.5618 28.45742 84.76965
2015-04-30 122.8086 28.53299 84.73932
2015-05-01 124.0000 28.57618 84.80000
```

or the put looks like:

```
structure(c(122.154509543852, 123.983621421486, 124.434078860684, 
    125.225787705634, 125.962885778852, 126.126687074014, 126.492320227327, 
    124.547751779181, 123.328974601471, 124.356047962478, 123.561779964634, 
    122.808613513252, 124, 28.1659442697104, 28.1119613477074, 28.079579550721, 
    28.1551370770225, 28.187532134368, 28.2846907856862, 28.3062786503438, 
    28.3494676400181, 28.3602615723469, 28.3818494370044, 28.4574202236651, 
    28.5329910103257, 28.57618, 84.6373035627333, 84.7282463827038, 
    84.7080380110033, 84.7484547544043, 84.7686631261047, 84.7989705363372, 
    84.8505569604793, 84.8100990385319, 84.6381991961199, 84.8303279995055, 
    84.769651411221, 84.7393234117153, 84.8), .Dim = c(13L, 3L), .Dimnames = 
    list(NULL, c("TLT", "PCY", "SHY")), index = structure(c(16540, 
16541, 16542, 16545, 16546, 16547, 16548, 16549, 16552, 16553, 
16554, 16555, 16556), class = "Date"), class = "zoo")
```

I want to apply linear regression (or first-order polynomial fitting) to the columns of this data frame and have the result be a vector with the values in the vector being the slope of the fitted line for each column of data. Is there a way to use ‘apply' and an anonymous function to do this with ‘lm', or is there a library function out there that will do this?

Comment: Can you show the formula to be used

Comment: Trying to use something like: apply(zz, 2, function(q) lm(q ~ time(q))) where zz is the zoo data frame. I need to retrieve the second coefficient for each column from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 apply(zz, 2, function(q) coef(lm(q ~ time(q)))[2])
```

Comment: Yes, perfect. Thank you. This gives the vector of slopes I wanted.